# Pandas groupby count values greater than given values in each group

Tags: python, pandas

I want to count how many values are greater than a given set of values in each group.
For instance, the `DataFrame` `df` is like:

```
print(df)

  item   A   B   C
0    a  -4  17 -15
1    a  19 -16  -3
2    a -18 -11 -13
3    b  -2   9   7
4    b  -9 -15 -14
5    b -20   2 -10
6    c -19   0 -10
7    c  11   3   4
8    d   5   0 -17
9    d   7   1  -1
```

and the condition `c` is another `DataFrame`, like

```
print(c)

  item  value
0    a      5
1    b     -1
2    c      2
3    d      1
```

The desired result looks like

```
        count
item   A   B   C
a      1   1   0
b      0   2   1
c      1   1   1
d      2   0   0
```

I searched questions about using the `pandas.groupby()` function with conditions, but the answers were based on "greater than one value", not for a set of values.

The pseudo-code might write as following...
I know it does not work properly...

```
df.groupby("item")[["A", "B", "C"]].apply(lambda x: x > c["value"] if df["item"] == c["item"]).size()
```

It would be greatly appreciated if any of you could help me.
Many thanks.

Comment: I see count of 2 for (b, B).

Comment: Sorry, that's my mistake. I have revised. Thank you, @jpp for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC

```
(df.set_index('item')).sub(c.set_index('item').reindex(df.item).value,axis=0).gt(0).groupby(level=0).sum()
Out[646]: 
        A    B    C
item               
a     1.0  1.0  0.0
b     0.0  2.0  1.0
c     1.0  1.0  1.0
d     2.0  0.0  0.0
```

Comment: So the logic is to subtract the values of items in `c` from the values of corresponding items in `df` and then sum the results which greater than zero. The trick is setting `item` as indexes for both `df` and `c` then reindexing according to the indexes of `df `.

Comment: @Huan if it is what you need can you consider accept it？